# Why do I get this Type error in seaborn jointplot function?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science, jupyter, data-analysis

I am learning seaborn library and I tried to copy the
code exactly same as that of the tutorial (in youtube) said but code is
being executed in the tutorial but I got stuck with this error.

I tried to use seaborn library `jointplot` function.
Type error occurs when the I load the dataframe in
the `jointplot` fucntion.

Jupyter shows the message for the type error:

> Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.jointplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=df, kind='hex')
```

Comment: What is the version of pandas and numpy you are using ?

Comment: pandas version is 1.2.3

Comment: numpy version is 1.20.1

Comment: Did the error still persists ? Or try updating the seaborn package.

Comment: I updated every package because this error also occured when I used pairplot function also. But suddenly it started occuring in jointplot function too.

Comment: What did you use to check your pandas/numpy versions?

Comment: I used pd.__version__ and np.__version__ in jupyter. After updating the libraries, the error is cleared. Thanks for the help.